# JS component not covered by fixed header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a fixed header (which covers the content that disappears when I scroll down). But it doesn't cover a js component caled ["Jssor Slider"](http://www.jssor.com/demos/different-size-photo-slider.html). I've seen simular effects with other js components on the net. Any ideas why this happens?

```
header {
    background: #f00;
    height: 136px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e6k4h25g/

Comment: Yep, there's a reason for the warning you saw, when you tried to create a link to jsFiddle. Didn't you read it?

Comment: @Teemu there were no warnings, I just hit save and copied the link.

Comment: @Teemu what did it say?

Comment: It says (or said) something like that you have to add some code to your post before you can link to fiddle, Also the post couldn't be saved before there was some code, or the link was removed (or obfuscated, as you did).

Comment: @Teemu oh, now I see... I thougt about a warning on jsfiddle.net (after creating the link = saving the fiddle) The warning on SO still exists, I ignored it by replacing the 'f' with a '*' into the link, you removed the '*', but you forgot to insert a 'f', that's why you didn't get the warning after your edit. But, I've updated the question, so I hope everything is ok now ;)

Comment: That was it! Blind me. Yep, the question is not perhaps the best possible, but at least much better, I've retracted my CV : ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not have to support older browsers go with

```
header {
    background: #f00;
    height: 136px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:20;
}
```

z-index can be anything. Just make sure it is higher than the z-index of your sliding element.

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/e6k4h25g/1/

Comment: I really hope nobody wouldn't have to support IE<=6 anymore?